# DeterministicProcess give me "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rule_code'"

Tags: datetime, linear-regression, deterministic

so I tried to run this code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.deterministic import CalendarFourier

y1 = close.copy()
y1.index = pd.to_datetime(y1.index)

fourier = CalendarFourier(freq='M',order=4)
dp1 = DeterministicProcess(constant=True,
                           index=y1.index,
                           order=1,
                           seasonal=True,
                           drop=True)
                           # additional_terms=[fourier])
X_time = dp1.in_sample()
X_time['NewYearsDay'] = (X_time.index.dayofyear == 1)

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
model.fit(X_time,y1)
y_deseason = y1 - model.predict(X_time)
y_deseason.name = 'sales_deseasoned'

ax = y_deseason.plot()
ax.set_title('Sales of School and Office Supplies (deseasonalized)');
```

and resulted in:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [136], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 y1.index = pd.to_datetime(y1.index)
      6 fourier = CalendarFourier(freq='M',order=4)
----> 7 dp1 = DeterministicProcess(constant=True,
      8                            index=y1.index,
      9                            order=1,
     10                            seasonal=True,
     11                            drop=True)
     12                            # additional_terms=[fourier])
     13 X_time = dp1.in_sample()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\deterministic.py:1179, in DeterministicProcess.__init__(self, index, period, constant, order, seasonal, fourier, additional_terms, drop)
   1177 if (seasonal or fourier) and period is None:
   1178     if period is None:
-> 1179         self._period = period = freq_to_period(self._index_freq)
   1180 if seasonal:
   1181     period = required_int_like(period, "period")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\tsatools.py:796, in freq_to_period(freq)
    794 if not isinstance(freq, offsets.DateOffset):
    795     freq = to_offset(freq)  # go ahead and standardize
--> 796 freq = freq.rule_code.upper()
    798 if freq == "A" or freq.startswith(("A-", "AS-")):
    799     return 1

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rule_code'
```

I thought that it maybe because of the datetime type that used to be "object", hence, changed it to "datetime" again, and yet error still coming. Any idea what went wrong here? highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
 dp1 = DeterministicProcess(constant=True,  index=y1.index,
  order=1,
 seasonal=True, ## Change this to False
 drop=True,
 additional_terms=[fourier])
```

Make this **seasonal=False** should help you provide the output...Reason might be in the data which you are processing...if seasonality has duplicate data (same date with multiple value or index is duplicated will not work ..so make seasonality false to make it work or Fix the duplicate dates either by aggregate or drop duplicate(keep='first').

### To fix 2nd option is while creating an index , we need to use resample (pandas) for 1 day and then use **seasonal = True** worked for me.

```
y1 = y1.set_index("date").resample('1D').pad()
```